# Foreign key of foreign key fields are not shown - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to create `form` for creating new `Person` object which has foreign key `Address` (all these models is just for practice). The problem is that, I can't see neither address label, nor text field for address in `PersonCreateForm` template. Here are my codes:

`person_app/models.py`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.ForeignKey('address_app.Address', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`address_app/models.py`:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

`person_app/forms.py`:

```
class CreatePersonForm(ModelForm):
    def save(self, commit=False):
        person= super(CreatePersonForm, self).save(commit=False)
        Person.objects.create(
                name = person.name,
                address = person.address.country)
```

`person.html`:

```
<h1>{{ form.name }}</h1> (name is visible)
<h1>{{ form.address }}</h1> (but address not)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CreatePersonForm` form should be something similar to this -

```
class CreatePersonForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ("name", "address")

    def save(self, commit=False):
        person= super(CreatePersonForm, self).save(commit=False)
        Person.objects.create(
                name = person.name,
                address = person.address.country)
```

try this and let me know if it works.